# phpmyadmin is showing some text page

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I have  Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I have installed phpmyadmin but when i type in my browser localhost/phpmyadmin it opens a wired page containing text like -

php

```
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main loader script
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */
use PMA\libraries\RecentFavoriteTable;

/**
 * Gets some core libraries and displays a top message if required
 */
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';

/**
 * display Git revision if requested
 */
require_once 'libraries/display_git_revision.lib.php';

/**
 * pass variables to child pages
 */
$drops = array(
    'lang',
    'server',enter code here
    'collation_connection',..
    'db',
    'table'
);
etc...........
```

Please let me know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Is apache running ? `sudo service apache2 status`

Comment: You cannot see php code from the browser, It seems that your php is not running on apache

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu documentation provides detailed information on how to install and enable PHP.
Considering you have Apache installed:

Install Apache PHP library

`$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5`

Enable the module

```
`$ sudo a2enmod php5`
```

And restart Apache

`$ sudo service apache2 restart`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#Installing_PHP_5

Answer (score 0):

The following command helped me to solve the same issue on Ubuntu20.04

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`